# How to display images in rows?

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

HI i have 10 images i need to display that in two row 5 in upside and 5 in bottom, i tried like this it shows them as two row but ng click is not working properly.

```
<div  class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 5 === 0" id="categorgrid">
        <div class="col col-20" ng-if="$index < images.length" ng-click="categoryclick(images[$index].src)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-20" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length" ng-click="categoryclick(images[$index].src)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 1].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-20" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length" ng-click="categoryclick(images[$index].src)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 2].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-20" ng-if="$index + 3 < images.length" ng-click="categoryclick(images[$index].src)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 3].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-20" ng-if="$index + 4 < images.length" ng-click="categoryclick(images[$index].src)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 4].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS 1.4 supports a filter called [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo). You can pipe it to your repeater and get the desired output. Here is an example in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5e3fQLU4Fq6N5QC2Ds5N?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="limitToExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('limitToExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div ng-repeat="number in numbers | limitTo: 5:0">Meow {{number}}</div>
</div>
</body>
```